# why is the button instantiated in the second instance but not the first?

Tags: java, android, oop

I have to ask this because I'm really struggling with OOP, and these are OOP concepts that I'm not understanding. Please help me. The code I've pasted below comes from the onCreate method for an Android Activity, but you may be able to answer even without knowing Android. Why isn't a button object instantiated for this button:

```
buttonSaveMem2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_mem2);
buttonSaveMem2.setOnClickListener(buttonSaveMem2OnClickListener);
```

while an object is created for this one?

```
Button buttonStartAnother = (Button)findViewByI(R.id.startanother);        
buttonStartAnother.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
{
```

Here is the full code for the method:

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   textSavedMem1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.savedmem1);
   textSavedMem2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.savedmem2);
   editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
   editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
   buttonSaveMem1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_mem1);
   buttonSaveMem2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_mem2);

   buttonSaveMem1.setOnClickListener(buttonSaveMem1OnClickListener);
   buttonSaveMem2.setOnClickListener(buttonSaveMem2OnClickListener);

   Button buttonStartAnother = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startanother);
   buttonStartAnother.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
```

Thank you.

Comment: will you post your layout xml?

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Why are you assuming that its an OOP problem? Clearly its a problem with your code. Learn to point the finger at the person who wrote it, not the language.

Comment: Oh dear. What if I ask my question this way: what is happening in the first block of code I posted, and what is happening in the second? I thought that they were doing the same thing, which I THINK is 1) Create button object 2)Set it to the correct layout button using its ID 3)Register the button as a listener.  Am I correct in this? Is this what both instances are doing? Why is the syntax different between the two>

Comment: Just want to add - this isn't my code. I am just trying to understand it so that I can do something similar in my own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your question and code posted here is you are just asking the difference between below two statements? and also why the statements were written like that?

```
buttonSaveMem2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_mem2);
```

and

```
Button buttonStartAnother = (Button)findViewByI(R.id.startanother);
```

Am I correct ? If yes, then read below answer otherwise forget it.

You are thinking the button **buttonStartAnother** instantiated as in second statement and button **buttonSaveMem2** not instantiated as in first statement.

Actually the button **buttonSaveMem2** declared before `onCreate()`. Why he did  like this because, he has to use the button **buttonSaveMem2** in other methods.

But button **buttonStartAnother** is not required to use in any other methods, so he declared inside **onCreate()**.

See below template for your code you will understand this.

```
public class Demo extends Activity {
    TextView textSavedMem1, textSavedMem2;
    Button buttonSaveMem1, buttonSaveMem2;
    EditText editText1, editText2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textSavedMem1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.savedmem1);
        textSavedMem2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.savedmem2);
        editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
        editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
        buttonSaveMem1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_mem1);
        buttonSaveMem2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_mem2);

        buttonSaveMem1.setOnClickListener(buttonSaveMem1OnClickListener);
        buttonSaveMem2.setOnClickListener(buttonSaveMem2OnClickListener);

        Button buttonStartAnother = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startanother);
        buttonStartAnother.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            }   
        });
    }       
    public void myMethod() {
        buttonSaveMem2.setText("myMethod called");
            // buttonSaveMem2 is accessible here because it is declared globally
        // buttonStartAnother.setText("hello");
            // If you remove comment on above line you will get error
            // because buttonStartAnother is invisible to this method
    }
}
```

I hope you will understand why the buttons are instantiated like that, if you didn't check `myMethod` in above code check that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an OOP problem, its in fact a coding problem with your implementation.

Read the basics of android... A widget is a view that is used by android to take input from the user, this can be a click or whatever. Specifically due to the way android is designed, all widgets(views) when being used must have some way to reference them... enter the method fineViewById(xx) this is used to find an widget/view with this particular id, often times coming from the R.java file.

Learn the **basics** of the language **before** you start coding this will save you a **lot** of time..

You can start here -> http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial

Comment: Thanks, JoxTraex. Obviously I don't understand enough to even formulate a proper question. Sorry to waste your time, folks.

Comment: The only effective way to ask a question is to learn the basics and then formulate an effective question, an effective question yields an effective answer. The only wasted time is when you don't learn what is wrong with the process of how you are attempting to achieve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost surely that your layout is missing a view with id `save_mem2`. The reason the second code block works is that there is a view with id `startanother`.